# Mount count is not reset after automatic fsck run at boot

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive, fsck

There's a PC running Xubuntu 15.10 (wily). The system is configured to run fsck on a partition when said partition is mounted 20 times. After that, the expected behaviour is that the mount count should reset, but it doesn't. This means that, as the mount count keeps growing past 20, fsck runs automatically every time the PC boots.

`tune2fs` shows that the filesystem state is clean and `smartctl` doesn't show any problem.

Work-arounds used so far:

- Use `tune2fs -C` to reset the mount count manually
- Boot from a Live CD and run fsck on the partition; this seems to reset the mount count properly when it finishes

When the mount count reaches 20 next time, the issue appears again: mount count is not reset after the automatic fsck run.

I have searched on this site and other places but haven't found any pointers as to what may be causing the issue. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of investigation, I found that the problem was in the `systemd-fsckd` service, from the `systemd` package. At the time of writing, the versions which are available in wily and xenial seem to contain the offending code (`225-1ubuntu9` and `229-4ubuntu4` respectively).

#### Solution

As the service is not necessary for the correct working of the system, a straightforward solution is just disabling it by running this command:

`systemctl mask systemd-fsckd.service systemd-fsckd.socket`

The downside is that now Plymouth won't report `fsck` progress. In fact, it won't even tell the user that a filesystem check is under way.

#### Explanation

A bit of background from the [`man` page of the service](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-fsckd.8.html):

> systemd-fsckd.service is a service responsible for receiving file system check progress, and communicating some consolidated data to console and plymouth (if running). It also handles possible check cancellations.
>
> **systemd-fsckd** receives messages about file system check progress from **fsck** through an UNIX domain socket [...]

The issue with this service is that it uses a hardcoded timeout of 30 seconds while doing an `epoll_wait` on the socket for progress information. If `fsck` doesn't report progress in less than 30 seconds, then `systemd-fsckd` closes the socket and exits with success without logging anything as far as I could see.

The next time that `fsck` writes in the (now closed) socket to report progress, it dies with a `SIGPIPE`. As `fsck` never finishes, the mount count is not reset then.

Comment: My situation: fsck runs at every boot (unless I reset counter manually). 30 seconds into test the progress is about 33 %, the whole test takes about 3 minutes to finish, percantage goes all the way to 99 % and then login screen shows up, everything seems fine. However no trace to be found in any log whatsover (fsck, boot, mountall). How I understand your answer the fsck should 'crash' after 30 seconds? Because the progress on my computer goes all the way, except the mount count is not reset and no trace left in any log file.

Comment: Hi @okolnost. If fsck reports steady progress (i.e. it doesn't stall for more than 30 seconds), then the root cause of your problem may be different. By default, systemd doesn't ouput much info in the logs. In my case, I enabled systemd's debug output and also used strace to troubleshoot the issue. Please, feel free to read [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ebautistabar/82811d492231700ab2471dd9048502b7), where I explain my approach. Hope you find it useful.